# Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, virtualbox, localhost, thunderbird

I can't seem to overcome the "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account" error. I'm using Virtualbox (ubuntu, virtual server, virtual workstation, localhost

Servername: angies2020-unix-server
local: cis4335.local

Attaching a Virtualbox screenshot of my postfix reconfiguration. I think the problem is here.

[VirtualBox postfix configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Be5.png)

***Edit*** Thunderbird

Opened Thunderbird email set up
Added name and email address:  name@cis4335.local and simple pw

Hit continue and it attempts to find me. Doesn't work of course and 
I'm taken to the Manual Configuration

incoming IMAP Outgoing SMTP

Changed server hostnames on both to servername.cis4335.local

Both ports are on auto, SSL on autodetect, Authentication on autodetect

Retest and receive the error

Comment: Where is your [autoconfig xml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration)?

Comment: And please, don't post screenshots of text that can just be copied and pasted.

Comment: Added an edit re:thunderbird. If you can use additional information please be specific. Fairly new user. Thank you for trying to help.